# unable to set element left properly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, position, offset

I am unable set one of the div's left position next to the table. I want "refreshing" div to appear on the right side of the table.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <table id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <th>
                Column 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 2
            </th>
            <th>
                Column 3
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Value 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Value 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Value 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Value 3
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="refreshing">
        Refreshing.....Please wait
</div>
</div>
```

This is how my java script looks like:

```
var leftPosition = $('#tbl').position().left + $('#tbl').width() + 20;

$("#refreshing").css({ top: 200, left: leftPosition, position: 'absolute' });
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdM9y/

Comment: can't you just use css to accomplish this?  why use javascript?

Comment: table gets added dynamically based on the ajax request made. number of columns are not fixed.

Comment: Maybe i mis understood your issue. Your code works, but why are you setting top property to 200? Here, with top set to 50 : http://jsfiddle.net/bdM9y/2/

Comment: @roasted : it does not work in IE

Comment: looks like then a bug in jquery specific version, works here for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/VhpQ2/

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment on dynamic loading but you could still achieve this via css - wrap the table in a sibling div and float both left inside the parent div; you can then align the 'refreshing' div bottom right inside the parent div for example, so it doesn't matter how many rows your table has

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of positioning, just wrapping table under a div will do the trick

```
    <div style="float: left">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/bdM9y/3/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE9 has an issue with jQuery 2.0.2. (may be in all IE versions only tested in 9)

It will work with:

- jQuery 2.x
- jQuery 1.x
- jQuery 1.9.1